# Localization in bash for the config file

Tags: json, bash, localization

I have a config json file. Here is an example:

```
{
    "tls": true,
    "port": 443,
    "room_server": "http:/prod.testwebsite.com/",
    "cert_path": "/test/prod/cert.pem"
}
```

I would like to set room_server/cert_path according to the machine i.e., 
http:/dev.testwebsite.com/ vs http:/prod.testwebsite.com/ and /test/dev/cert.pem vs /test/prod/cert.pem.

How to accomplish this substitution in bash?

Comment: Is changing all instances of 'prod' to 'dev' what you need? have you tried using `sed`?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. It was just an example. It could be arbitrary. Something like m4 might work here. But I wanted to check if anything easier with bash.

Comment: What about `sed "s/prod/dev/g" yourfile.json`? Change to whathever you need and include the `-i` flag to do an inplace substitution of the file or redirect output to another file if you prefer. You can also use a variable if using in a script, ie `sed "s/$1/$2/g" yourfile.json`.

Comment: `sed` is not appropriate for JSON; use something like `jq` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tool like `jq` to modify JSON.

```
$ jq '.room_server="http:/dev.testwebsite.com" | .cert_path="/test/dev/cert.pem"' config.json
{
  "tls": true,
  "port": 443,
  "room_server": "http:/dev.testwebsite.com",
  "cert_path": "/test/dev/cert.pem"
}
```